# jQuery Rating System Modification

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have built a jQuery 5 star rating system, ratings are inserted/stored in database along with no of hits, I am having a problem in inserting rating into database when any star is clicked repeatedly.

I.e., if a star is continuously clicked the rating does not get inserted but hits get inserted which then effect the new resulting rating.

I need to add some delay or stop the click function to fire again, it would be better if a delay can be added to click function.

I am trying stop click function to fire again this way but its not working.

**jQuery:**

```
        $('.u-rating').click(function (e){
    var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    var rating = ($(this).index()+1)/2;
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"rating.php",
        data: {rating:rating, id:id},
        cache: false,
        success: function(data1)          
           {
            get_rating();
            $('#u-rating p').html('Rating Submitted');
           }            
         });
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            return false;
     });
```

How do I stop people from rating multiple times?

Comment: It sounds like you ought to be enforcing this from the server, just as you are preventing additional votes.

Comment: i am not trying to prevent additional votes, just preventing repeated votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that your real issue that your backend is registering just the hits but not the ratings -  and you should probably focus on fixing the issue, not covering it with a band-aid.

Nevertheless, to address your question: You can use [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to bind the click handler just one, and then re-bind on every success (and error). See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H5gxa/1/) for an example. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<button id="button">Vote!</button>​
```

JS:

```
var postClick = function () {
    console.log('click fired!!');
    el = $(this);
    el.prop('disabled', true);
    //var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    //var rating = ($(this).index()+1)/2;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"/echo/json/",
        //data: {rating:rating, id:id},
        cache: false,
        success: function(data1){
            //get_rating();
            //$('#u-rating p').html('Rating Submitted');
            console.log('ajax success, starting timeout peridod. Clicks will not register now, for the next 5 seconds!');
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#button').one('click', postClick);
                el.prop('disabled', false);  
                console.log('Clicks are re-enabled!');
            }, 5000);
        } 
    });
}

$('#button').one('click', postClick);
```

​

Comment: Tried Not working, click events fire again when not re-bind in success function.

Comment: Updated answer with link to jsfiddle and slightly clearer code

Comment: Yeah this sounds like a back-end issue. `if (new_rating) { insert_new_rating(); insert_hit(); }`

Comment: Imagine the following scenario: User votes, realizes it has clicked the wrong rating, clicks again, nothing happens, site feels broken.

Comment: @Jan i tried this first it didnt work, `$update_rating = mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE..); if($update_rating){$update_hits = mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE..);`

Comment: @Jan updated example with disabled non-clickable button for better UX

Answer (score 1):

If your voters are logged-in users, store all ratings made by these users in a table with their user_id, then there's absolutely no problem keeping track of votes. If not, store them in a table with a date and an ip-address.

Since ip's can renew and point to a different user after an approximate interval, you can set a timeout date of about at day/week or so. This would have the drawback that users can keep voting once a day/week (if they haven't changed ip's), I don't know if that's acceptable in your project.

Then you can just (pseudo-code)

```
if (not exists sql("select rating from voteditems 
                      where ipaddress = @ip_adress // Switch to "user_id" if that's what you're using
                      and item_id = @item_id
                      and datevoted > getdate()-1")) // Or -7 or whatever interval you choose
{
  insert_rating();
}
```

The hits can be counted as

```
select count(rating) from voteditems where item_id = @item_id
```